# CSS Notifications fade

Tags: php, jquery, html, notifications

Im creating a small web app and I have used AJAX in a few functions such a creating and deleting certain objects.

To notify the user I have used PHP to echo a HTML notification on to the screen depending on weather the object was successfully created or not.

```
if ($query) {
 //response to ajax call if successful
  echo '<div class="alert alert-success"><a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a><h4 class="alert-heading">Success!</h4>Object Added!</div>';
```

}

The problem is, over time the notifications build up on the screen as there is no refresh to remove them.

I have a jQuery function that can remove the alerts every 5 seconds shown below

```
function clearAlerts(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.alert').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 5000);
    }
```

But I dont know how to call this function every time a notification is added to the page, is
there anyway to use jQuery to perhaps detect when a notification has been echoed on to the page, or to run this jQuery function each time they are added.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Put this tag directly inside each HTML snippet you are generating, you can style it in any way you like:

```
<span class="close-notification">Close</span>
```

Then use this piece of JS to remove it when clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', '.close-notification', function(){
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(); // could use .remove(), .slideUp() etc
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, but not quite what I need. I have a way for the user to manually close the notification, however if they choose not to do this then the notifications will keep building up and so I need away to automatically removing them every 5 seconds

Comment: even without seeing code! +1 But perhaps it is better to use an <a>, because the user will then see it's clickable.

Comment: @Ben_Hawk : why would you want that? It's the users decision.

Comment: The notifications will popup regularly and so it will remove the need for the user to keep closing them, and will prevent notifications building up on the screen when the user does not close them.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is possible, by jQuery. First, add a class to the notification div, for example:

```
<div class="notification">Notification</div>
```

Then this jQuery:

```
$(".notification").live("ready", function(){
                $(".notification").setDelay(5000).fadeOut("slow");
            });
```